# Logic to covert json stringify into multiple array

Tags: javascript, html

```
var result = [
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "age": 12,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U121"
    },
    {
        "Name": "jkl",
        "age": 22,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U122"
    },
    {
        "Name": "xyz",
        "age": 32,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U123"
    },{
        "Name": "mno",
        "age": 42,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U124"
    }
]
```

I want to iterate this in javascript and create td, tr element in such a way that abc, jkl come in one row and xyz, mno come in second row. Can anyone help me with the logic?

Comment: What is the hard part? Iterating through the object? Creating table elements? Adding content to the elements? Something else? Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: Adding content to td and tr in javascript is what I am having difficulty. I am using https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-json-data-to-a-html-table-using-javascript-jquery/ now to find a solution.

Comment: Please show your code, then we can add the content part.

Comment: Geeks ... Take a look at [this jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/16kwjyoa/1/) ...

Comment: @Teemu I have marked the answer given by Shubham

Comment: Yes, I can see that. If you've followed the fiddle link I've included in my comment above, you now know how to do the task efficiently ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
var input = [
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "age": 12,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U121"
    },
    {
        "Name": "jkl",
        "age": 22,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U122"
    },
    {
        "Name": "xyz",
        "age": 32,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U123"
    },{
        "Name": "mno",
        "age": 42,
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "id":"U124"
    }
];

function test(){
let i=0;
    let outhtml="";
    
    input.forEach(ele => {
      i=i%2;
      let addRow=(i==0);
      
      //After 2 elements add row
      if (addRow){
        outhtml += "</tr><tr>"
      }
      
      //add td
      outhtml += "<td>"+ele.Name+"</td>"
      i++;
    })
    
    //Remove </tr> from start
    outhtml = outhtml.substring(5, outhtml.lenght);
    document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = outhtml;
}

test();
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  
</table>
```

Comment: i cannot use jquery.

Comment: Removed jquery @spuamtiitl